# Is this suspension fork user-serviceable?

Tags: fork, suspension

This is my fork and I want to open the suspension legs, inspect them, then reassemble, but I don't see how to get in there.  Any suggestions on what tools and procedure to use?

Is this user-serviceable at all?

The bike is a [Genesis GS29](http://genbikes.com/mountain/genesis-29-gs29-black-green.php).

Related questions:

What method of damping are they using .. is this springs only?

Do I have damping for both compression and rebound?

Would I have to take care to prevent springs from flying off while disassembling?

Would I need a special tool to compress springs during reassembly?

Pictures:

[image: Suspension fork bottoms]

[image: Suspension fork crown]

[image: Suspension fork crown open]

Comment: Its a BSO. I wouldn't sink too much time or parts into it.

Comment: With the ewear and tear that forks looks to have had you may be better just getting another cheap replacement, may be able to find a cheap SR Suntour or RST for a reasonable price in the classifieds or craiglist. If i had to guess it's probably a spring only fork and is not serviceable as others have said. You could spray a liberal amount of lubricant down into the legs and compress them repeatedly. This may or may not help it function a little better.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To expand on Batman's comment, its a [BSO](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/887/19705) because its from walmart and built down to a price from low grade components.

So, the forks will not be user-serviceable.  They won't be serviceable at all even by a shop, and the only way to adjust them is to change them completely.

How do we know its a [BSO](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/887/19705)?  Because the specs say things like

- "Tyres, 29 inch" without mention of width/height
- "Front/Rear Derailler - Shimano"   <-- there's a massive range.
- "Available at walmart.com"   That's a pretty damning indictment right there.

Its a fine bike for tootling about, but don't sink any money into upgrading it, other than the normal replacement-wear parts like chain, cassette, and brake pads.   If you're interested in riding more and better, save your money toward a better bike.

*Answer because its too long for a comment.*